# How to make two mutually exclusive segmented rows with Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I use [Eureka library](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and i want to make the two mutually exclusive segmented rows with this code:

```
        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("weight1") { row in
            row.options = ["До 3 кг", "До 5 кг"]
            row.value = "До 3 кг"
        }.onChange{ [weak self] row in
            let weight2Row: SegmentedRow<String>! = self?.form.rowByTag("weight2")
            weight2Row.value = nil
        }

        <<< SegmentedRow<String>("weight2") { row in
            row.options = ["До 16 кг", "У меня авто"]
        }.onChange{ [weak self] row in
            let weight1Row: SegmentedRow<String>! = self?.form.rowByTag("weight1")
            weight1Row.value = nil
        }
```

But if i click on second Segmented row the first segmented controll don't clean up the selection

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the guide - section [How to set the form values using a dictionary](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-set-the-form-values-using-a-dictionary)

> If the form was already displayed we have to reload the visible rows
>   either by reloading the table view tableView.reloadData() or invoking
>   updateCell() to each visible row.

so just call `weight2Row.updateCell()` to have the new values reflect.